# How make concatenate function faster

Tags: vba, excel

Hi everyone hope you are doing well. I have a code that depends on a concatenate process to be used later. The piece of code where I make the concatenate is the following:

```
i=2 
Do while ws.cells(i,2) <> 0
 ws.cells(i,1) = "=concatenate(C" & i & ", D" & i & ")" 
 i = i + 1 
Loop
```

The problem is if I have a big sample, it takes too much time to complete. Do you guys know any way to make it better and faster? Thanks in advance

Comment: First, don't use `concatenate`, ever.   `"AAA" & "BBB" = "AAABBB"`.  If you're joining a bunch of cell and have Excel 2016, stick with worksheet function `TEXTJOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between Formulas and Arrays:

```
Formula - Total Rows: 1,048,576, Time: 2.414 sec
Arrays  - Total Rows: 1,048,576, Time: 3.758 sec
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub JoinCDinA1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, tr As String, t As Double

    t = Timer
    Set ws = Sheet1
    lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        .Formula = "= C2 & D2"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With

    tr = "Formula - Total Rows: " & Format(lr, "#,###,###")
    Debug.Print tr & ", Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub

Public Sub JoinCDinA2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur1 As Variant, ur2 As Variant, r As Long, lr As Long
    Dim tr As String, t As Double

    t = Timer
    Set ws = Sheet1
    lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ur1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lr, 1))
    ur2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells(lr, 4))
    For r = 1 To lr - 1
        ur1(r, 1) = ur2(r, 1) & ur2(r, 2)
    Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lr, 1)) = ur1

    tr = "Arrays  - Total Rows: " & Format(lr, "#,###,###")
    Debug.Print tr & ", Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I'll try tomorrow, but pretty confident that array is what I need.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Comment: Actually, I proposed the array method in case the string concatenation was more complex than the original question sampled for and the benefits should exhibit in a more complex situation.

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways to assign all at once without loop. For example:

```
ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Formula = "= C2 & D2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Bulk loading an array, processing said array then dropping the results back to the worksheet *en masse* is almost always appreciably faster than a loop.

```
dim i as long, vals as variant
with worksheets("sheet1")
    vals = .range(.cells(2, "C"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(0, 2))
    for i=lbound(vals, 1) to ubound(vals, 1)
        vals(i, 1) = join(array(vals(i, 1), vals(i, 2)), vbnullstring)
    next i
    redim preserve vals(lbound(vals, 1) to ubound(vals, 1), 1 to 1)
    .cells(2, "A").resize(ubound(vals, 1), 1) = vals
end with
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped! Your answer increase my knowledge, gonna try tomorrow.